# Youtube Downloader - ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm working on learning JavaScript and I figured the best way is to dive into a project after watching several tutorials and taking some online courses. I'm looking to create my on online Youtube video and audio down loader.

I've downloaded the ytdl-core files from https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core and I wanted to know how to properly link this to my HTML document. Do I need to link all the provided script files or is there only one or two necessary to get the basic functionality?

Here is a screenshot of the file structure from the github link.

[ytdl file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWO9Z.png)

This is my first post and I'm sure there is some additional information that my be helpful so please let me know what I can provide to be more precise.

Thank you,
Phillip

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

ytdl-core is a node package for downloading and getting info regrading youtube videos. If you are using node.js as your backend simply install the package by running followinf command.

```
npm i 'ytdl-core'
```

Then you can use it in any backend js file.
For example below code snippet gives some information regarding youtube video.

```js
const ytdl=require('ytdl-core')
const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KX06ksuS6Xo'  //replace with your video url
async function getInfo(url){
const info=await ytdl.getBasicInfo(url);
return info
}
getInfo();
```